# Get content element in different languages

Tags: typo3, typoscript

It is easy to get a content element with TypoScript:

```
lib.getSingleCE = CONTENT
lib.getSingleCE {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        uidInList.field = myUid
        pidInList = 0
    }
}
```

and in fluid template:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.getSingleCE" data="{myUid: 3333}"/>
```

However, I am completely lost when it gets to translation. How is it possible to get the translated version of content element 3333 in the foreign language?

Answer (score 0):

I always thought that TypoScript handles translated records by default.

But if nothing else works, I'd do it like this:

```
page = PAGE

page.10 = CONTENT
page.10 {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    uidInList = 3842896
  } 
}

[siteLanguage('languageId') > 0]
page.10.select.uidInList >
page.10.select.where = l18n_parent = 3842896
[global]
```

If you have more than one translation language you need to add `sys_language_uid` to the where clause.

Of course this solution works only if the record is translated properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it does not work for me. I get this sql: 'SELECT * FROM `tt_content` WHERE (`tt_content`.`uid` = 0) AND (l18n_parent = 9895 AND sys_language_uid = 1) AND ... seems that `tt_content`.`uid` = is always included wether defined or not.

Comment: I think CONTENT does respect language handling unless you specify an UID which you do in your original sample code.
As you can see in FSC styles.content.get definition there is no sys lang defined there, but it handles languages without additional config.

If possible I'd store this record on a dedicated page in a dedicated column, so you can select by PID which should handle your language.

If this is not possible I'd rather go with cObj "RECORD" or try a dataProcessor.

Answer (score 0):

Go for **RECORDS** instead of **CONTENT**, when you want to fetch single elements. AFAIK this will apply translations automatically by default.

```
lib.getSingleCE = RECORDS
lib.getSingleCE {
  source.field = myUid
  tables = tt_content
  dontCheckPid = 1
}
```